# Accessing redirect URL from inside Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have an app I've been developing in React, and it has a callback URI to process the OIDC tokens for authentication.

This all works locally, but when attempting to make it work on Cordova, there's always a problem with redirection - I can redirect to any external site without issues, but I can't direct to any app endpoints, even when I am using a custom URL scheme.

I am trying to do this in several different browsers - WkWebKit, SafariViewController, and SFAuthentication - with no success.

I don't feel that OIDC should be this hard on Cordova - is there any specific setup that will work in 2019? It seems like the standards for this have changed 3 or 4 times in the past 2-3 years.

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of OAUTH related Cordova plugins, why not check them out instead of manually dealing with this issue? "standards" for this (if there's such a thing) keep changing, so using a plugin is highly recommended in this case.

Comment: I have looked extensively into this issue. There seems to be no "standard" implementation due to Apple changing standards something like four times over the past 2-3 years. I was using OIDC JS Client, but it appears that this isn't supported for Cordova-related applications now. AppAuthJS may be another solution, but that still won't get rid of the need for a redirect_uri in app to work. I can't get a redirect_uri working - that's the real crux of the matter.

Comment: Ostensibly I could theoretically use inappbrowser, get the value that way, and spoof the browser so that Google and Facebook are none-the-wiser, but that seems hacky and unsupported.